# two dimensional linear regression coefficients

Tags: python, math, scikit-learn, linear-algebra, linear-regression

I am doing linear regression with two dimensional variables:

```
 filtered[['p_tag_x', 'p_tag_y', 's_tag_x', 's_tag_y']].head()

     p_tag_x      p_tag_y            s_tag_x     s_tag_y
35    589.665646  1405.580171        517.5       1636.5
36    589.665646  1405.580171        679.5       1665.5
100   610.546851  2425.303250        569.5       2722.0
101   610.546851  2425.303250        728.0       2710.0
102   717.237730  1411.842428        820.0       1616.5



clt = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clt.fit(filtered[['p_tag_x', 'p_tag_y']], filtered[['s_tag_x', 's_tag_y']])
```

I am getting following coefficients of the regression:

```
clt.coef_

array([[ 0.4529769 , -0.22406594],
       [-0.00859452, -0.00816968]])
```

And the residues (X_0, and Y_0)

```
clt.residues_
array([ 1452.97816371,    69.12754694])
```

How I should I understand the above coefficients matrix in terms of the regression line ?

Comment: The first and second code-block do not match each other (LR vs. Ransac?). Furthermore we don't know your dataframe, but it seems you are doing multi-target regression (with or without your knowledge). Add some more specifics (if question still resides after interpretation of the latter)

Comment: @sascha please see my edit.

Comment: Then those are just 2 regressors fitted and all basics (of linear regression; wikipedia) apply (to each). What's unclear?

Comment: @sascha It's not clear why I get as coefficients 2 vectors of 1x2. How I bring it to the linear equations ? Can you write me the equations...

Comment: You got some samples, each with 2 features. Given one target, you get 1 vector of 1x2 which together with the intercept_, if used, can create the line. But in your case you got 2 targets; so instead of 1 vector 1x2 coeffs, you got 2 vectorx 1x2; each a line corresponding to LinearRegression for target 0, then 1.

Comment: This is called Multi-output regression. You can [see here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multioutput-regression) for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i already explained in the comments, you got an extra-dimension in your `coef_` as well as `intercept_` because you got *2 targets* (`y.shape(n_samples, n_targets)`). In this case sklearn will fit *2 independent regressors*, one for each target.

You then can just take those *n regressors* apart and handle each one on it's own.

The [formula](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#generalized-linear-models) of your regression line is still:

```
y(w, x) = intercept_ + coef_[0] * x[0] + coef_[1] * x[1] ...
```

Sadly your example is a bit harder to visualize because of the dimensionality.

Consider this a demo, with a lot of ugly hard-coding for this specific case (and bad example data!):

#### Code:

```
# Warning: ugly demo-like code using a lot of hard-coding!!!!!

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sklearn import linear_model

X = np.array([[589.665646,  1405.580171],
              [589.665646,  1405.580171],
              [610.546851,  2425.303250],
              [610.546851,  2425.303250],
              [717.237730,  1411.842428]])

y = np.array([[517.5,       1636.5],
              [679.5,       1665.5],
              [569.5,       2722.0],
              [728.0,       2710.0],
              [820.0,       1616.5]])

clt = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clt.fit(X, y)

print(clt.coef_)
print(clt.residues_)

def curve_0(x, y):  # target 0; single-point evaluation hardcoded for 2 features!
    return clt.intercept_[0] + x * clt.coef_[0, 0] + y * clt.coef_[0, 1]

def curve_1(x, y):  # target 1; single-point evaluation hardcoded for 2 features!
    return clt.intercept_[1] + x * clt.coef_[1, 0] + y * clt.coef_[1, 1]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

xs = [np.amin(X[:, 0]), np.amax(X[:, 0])]
ys = [np.amin(X[:, 1]), np.amax(X[:, 1])]

# regressor 0
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], y[:, 0], c='blue')
ax.plot([xs[0], xs[1]], [ys[0], ys[1]], [curve_0(xs[0], ys[0]), curve_0(xs[1], ys[1])], c='cyan')

# regressor 1
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], y[:, 1], c='red')
ax.plot([xs[0], xs[1]], [ys[0], ys[1]], [curve_1(xs[0], ys[0]), curve_1(xs[1], ys[1])], c='magenta')

ax.set_xlabel('X[:, 0] feature 0')
ax.set_ylabel('X[:, 1] feature 1')
ax.set_zlabel('Y')

plt.show()
```

#### Output:

[image]

#### Remarks:

- You don't have to calculate the formula by yourself: `clt.predict()` will do that!
- The code-lines involving `ax.plot(...)` use the assumption, that our line is defined by just 2 points (linear)!

Comment: I was under the impression that only a single regression was somehow able to predict the 2D output. But I was not able to wrap my head around the equation. Your answer cleared a lot of things ! Learnt something new today :)